# php htaccess issue redirection

Tags: .htaccess

I hava a some problem in .htaccess..

my site url is for ex. `www.example.com/`

when we go to city page using dropdown..its come to `index.php?city=cityname` (its to be correct)

when we go to about us page it comes to be indexpage instead of about us page

city page url : `www.example.com/cityname`

about us url : `www.example.com/about-us`

below htaccess code;

when we go about us page it comes to index page

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?city=$1
RewriteRule ^about-us$ about_us.php
```

Comment: To help clarify, tell us what exactly is the expected behavior, and what exactly is happening instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just change the order of rewrites. So, use this:

```
RewriteRule ^about-us$ about_us.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?city=$1
```

Comment: @Viju Please select the above as answer if it helped. The question still lists under unanswered questions.